# Matching values in two columns of inconsistent length

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to retrive the results to a lab from a provided excel. Unfortunately, the excel data is structured as such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tests':['a\nb\nc', 'b\nc\na'], 'Results':['1.2\n3.4\n4', '2.3\n1\n1']})
df
   Tests       Results
0 a\nb\nc  1.2\n3.4\n4
1 b\nc\na  2.3\n1\n1
```

I want to be able to return the result that matches test 'a':

```
    Tests      Results   a result
0 a\nb\nc  1.2\n3.4\n4        1.2
1 b\nc\na    2.3\n1\n1          1
```

I know I can separate the different lines in the test and/or result column using

```
tests = df['Tests'].str.split('\n', expand=True)
```

When I try to apply that into a for loop (I hate for-loops too but can't think of a better method for this) I am not successful:

```
for row in df:
tests = df['Tests'].str.split('\n', expand=True)
if tests[0] == 'a':
    df['result'] = tests[0]
    #...and on through each possible row of col of tests expanded
```

I'm confident a better way exists, any direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) after expanding all columns in `df` then do some reshaping with [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) (assuming each test value appears at most once per cell) to create a reasonable lookup table:

```
lookup_df = (
    pd.concat(
        [df[col].str.split('\n', expand=True) for col in df],
        keys=df.columns,
        axis=1
    )
        .rename_axis('index')
        .stack()
        .reset_index()
        .pivot(index='index', columns='Tests', values='Results')
        .add_prefix('results_')  # Optional Column Prefix
        .astype('float64')  # If wanting Numeric values
)
```

```
Tests results_a results_b results_c
index                              
0           1.2       3.4         4
1             1       2.3         1
```

This can be [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to `df`:

```
df = df.join(lookup_df)
```

`df`:

```
     Tests      Results results_a results_b results_c
0  a\nb\nc  1.2\n3.4\n4       1.2       3.4         4
1  b\nc\na    2.3\n1\n1         1       2.3         1
```

---

Alternatively, assuming the expanded tests and results are guaranteed to have the same dimensions when split and expanded. And we're only looking for one of the test results we can use numpy indexing to find the Results and create the column:

```
tests = df['Tests'].str.split('\n', expand=True)
results = df['Results'].str.split('\n', expand=True)
df['results_a'] = results.to_numpy()[tests.eq('a').to_numpy()]
```

`df`:

```
     Tests      Results results_a
0  a\nb\nc  1.2\n3.4\n4       1.2
1  b\nc\na    2.3\n1\n1         1
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get these to work. With option 1 I had to first separate the tests and results from the original df because the original df had many other columns of mixed dtypes. Option 2 worked even better, but I added .fillna('') because there were more tests than results in many cases.